# Creating a textfield with only bottom Line in Ios

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

Is is possible to create a Textfield in Ios which shows  only bottom border line and not upper and side lines. if Yes, how can i implement this

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Here is how to do it:

```
CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
border.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height);
border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
[textField.layer addSublayer:border];
textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is there any way by which i can set default text to a textbox but when i do txtview.text.length it still shows 0 i.e length should only increment when i enter real text

Comment: You can put in a `UILabel`.

Comment: Can u explain more about it

Comment: I'd be happy to if you send me a link to your new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429527/default-text-in-a-text-field here is the link

Comment: This just displays a extra bottom border and keeps displaying the top and sides?? iOS 7

Comment: Thanks for the code,but do you have any idea why it's not drawing the underline whenthe textfileds are placed in static tableview cells(UITableViewController + Static Cells).
Any work around would be appreciated.

Comment: Should the last parameter to `CGRectMake` be `borderwidth`?

Answer (score 23):

Updated for Swift 3.0

```
extension UITextField {    

    func useUnderline() {
        let border = CALayer()
        let borderWidth = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :self.frame.size.height - borderWidth), size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))
        border.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Swift:

```
extension UITextField {

    func useUnderline() {

        let border = CALayer()
        let borderWidth = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
yourtextFieldName.useUnderline()
```

Comment: border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, self.frame.size.width, borderWidth)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use CALayer to textfield with only bottom Line in Ios

```
CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.passwordField.frame.size.height - 1, self.passwordField.frame.size.width, 1.0f);
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
[self.passwordField.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

Answer (score -1):

User4645956's solution in Swift

```
private func addBottomLineToTextField(textField : UITextField) {
    let border = CALayer()
    let borderWidth = CGFloat(1.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth
    textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Usage:

```
    self.addBottomLineToTextField(usernameTextField)
    self.addBottomLineToTextField(passwordTextField)
```