# Default text in a text Field

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can i Put default text in a textfield which should disappear when i focus particular Text field for entry.

If I read the Size of textfield i.e textfield.text.size it should return me 0 until default text is present.

Comment: You can use placeholder via XIB.

Comment: if you don't want to use placeholder than set default text in textfield and clear it when **textFieldShouldBeginEditing** Delegate method called!

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati buddy in that case it will take the length of text greater than 0

Comment: explain more what exactly you want to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its very Simple. you can use PlaceHolder Text. And the property attributedPlaceholder is available from iOS6. So do not use it if your app supports iOS5.

For `Objective C`

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"DemoText" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
```

**Update:**

For `swift`

```
var placeholder = NSAttributedString(string: "DemoText", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
var textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30));
textField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder;
self.view.addSubview(textField)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the [placeholder](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/placeholder) property of UITextField class.

Answer (score 3):

For the default text, you can use the property placeHolder of UITextField.

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *placeholder;
```

Answer (score 1):

For default text, you can set text as placeholder text.

Programatically

`[txtField setPlaceholder:@"My placeholder"];`

Or you can keep `text as placeholder text` from xib as well.