# How to customize UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428402/creating-a-textfield-with-only-bottom-line-in-ios) to create a custom UITextField, however, I couldn't get the same result, here's how I did it:

**Method 1** (exactly like the original answer):

```
extension UITextField {

    func useUnderLine() {
        let border = CALayer()
        let borderWidth = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstTextField.useUnderLine()
}
```

**Method 2** (using a custom class):

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let borderWidth = CGFloat(1.0)
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
}
```

Both methods failed to work, however, I got different results for them:

[image]

first text field uses method 1, the other 3 use method 2

> I want a textfield with only the bottom line, how do I get that?

**Edit** (here's how outlets are set):

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: CustomTextField! { didSet { secondTextField.delegate = self } }
@IBOutlet weak var thirdTextField: CustomTextField! { didSet { thirdTextField.delegate = self } }
@IBOutlet weak var fourthTextField: CustomTextField! { didSet { fourthTextField.delegate = self } }
```

Comment: Add `firstTextField.borderStyle = .none` to method 1?

Comment: In method 2 self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black is black

Comment: Yeah black background and white border is what I want, different from the original answer.

Comment: In method 1 black background color is not set

Comment: @user2071152 I tried to set it with `self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor` or `border.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor`, both failed to work

Comment: @user2071152 I tried to set it with `self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor` or `border.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor`, both failed to work

Comment: self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black add this in method 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you´re using the **Storyboard** to create your `textField` use the following:

```
firstTextField.borderStyle = .none
firstTextField.layoutIfNeeded()

let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(2.0)
border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor

print(firstTextField.frame)
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: firstTextField.frame.size.height - width, width:  firstTextField.frame.size.width, height: firstTextField.frame.size.height)
border.borderWidth = width

firstTextField.layer.addSublayer(border)
firstTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

If you´re creating your `textField` **programmatically** use the following:

```
let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 100, height: 20))

let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(2.0)
border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

border.borderWidth = width
textField.borderStyle = .none
textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
textField.layer.masksToBounds = true

self.view.addSubview(textField)
```

Will give you:
[image]

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer clear. Now it's changed, but it's totally black

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the `layoutIfNeeded()` made it work

Comment: I want to thank you for the code and sample, but if I rotate to landscape the layer does not get updated. I used viewDidLayoutSubviews still no luck. Can someone help ?

Comment: @AbuTaareq, it´s because the frame is hardcoded in this example just to demonstrate the functionality.