# How do I make my textfields as lines instead of boxes?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

This is the desired design for the Textfields:

[image: This is the desired design for the Textfields]

This is what I have designed:

[image: This is what I have designed]

Do I have to import some libraries or install some pods? Is there a programmatic way to do it?

Comment: Nope you can draw bottom border instead of whole border

Comment: you can set border of textfield to none  and add little views below every textfield

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Google something like ["ios custom uitextfield"](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ios%20custom%20uitextfield) and use the first [github link](https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects) that pops up.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428402/creating-a-textfield-with-only-bottom-line-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

*Below is the code.*

```
@IBOutlet weak var fullName: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bottomBorder = CALayer()
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: fullName.frame.size.height-1, width: fullName.frame.size.width, height: 1.0)
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    fullName.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
}
```

*Output:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In swift, I've achieved it with following code :

```
class viewController: UIViewController 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!

    let layer : CALayer = CALayer()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
         textfield.borderStyle = .none // can do this in xib or storyboard too
         textfield.layer.masksToBounds = true
         layer?.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
         layer?.borderWidth = 1.0
         textfield.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }

   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
   {

        layer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                               y: textfield.frame.size.height - 1,
                               width:  textfield.frame.size.width,
                               height: 1.0)



    }

}
```

Comment: As a note: this is one of the cases where it is good practice to define the layer to be of type `CALayer!` because `viewDidLoad` will definitely get called before `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 0):

You can use CosmicMind's Material framework and use [textfield](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material#textfield) object. You can install the framework via cocoapods and you can follow the examples they have on the repo.